# Сервер Apache стоит сейчас использовать или это уже мертвый проект?

Tags: apache, http, apache2

Сервер Apache стоит сейчас использовать или это уже мертвый проект? Чтобы не закидали помидорами, сразу скажу, мне нравится Апач, но сейчас конец 2020 года и на Апач модуля HTTP3 (QUIC) я не нашел.

Comment: дык он еще даже не стандарт, только драфты есть, опять же насколько я понимаю высоконагруженному серверу квик противопоказан пока, т.к. он в разы больше кушает процессор из-за того, что нет поддержки аппаратной разгрузки, как у TCP.

Comment: Apache - это не совсем *(не только)* веб-сервер, это [фонд](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Software_Foundation), финансирующий открытые разработки. Ну и с чего бы он умер? Последняя версия веб-сервера вышла меньше пол года назад. Странные критерии живучести проекта - поддержка QUIC. Не поддерживает, значит мертв? А может такое быть, что ему этого вообще не надо поддерживать?